Проблема с производительностью больших объектов godot
Почему-то у меня в проекте если сделать CSGBox3D больше области видимости камеры сильно понижается фпс.

Вот результат когда CSGBox3D меньше области камеры

Вот результат когда CSGBox3D больше области видимости камеры
Фпс показан слева сверху
Я пробовал откреплять все скрипты от всех объектов, у которых они были, думая, что проблема с производительностью связана с большим кол-вом кода. А так как я познаю godot в процессе создания проекта, естественно, код будет не оптимизирован. Но нет, фпс всё так же был мал. Проблема решалась при понижении разрешения самого проекта, или при удалении CSGBox3D, но для меня это не вариант. Я даже пробовал заменять CSGBox3D на другую модель, но и это проблему не решало, и я пришёл к выводу, что проблема именно в размере объекта. Неужели у godot такие проблемы с большими объектами?

Документация в принципе рекомендует не использовать CSGBox3D, так что лучше расскажите, зачем он вам?

А ещё я не могу воспроизвести проблему у себя, при любом размере CSGBox3D я получаю одни и те же 3500 фпс: https://i.sstatic.net/UDB3SC4E.png — это может говорить о том, что в вашем проекте происходит что-то, о чём вы не рассказали
